# Доработка боя с ботом в браузерной игре

Tags: php

я сделал бой:

```
<table>
<tr>

<TD><div align="left"><?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM startpoke WHERE id_poke = '".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die("can't connect") ;    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
echo "<br>{$row['name_poke']}" ;
echo " - {$row['level']} lvl";
echo "<br>{$row['img']}";
echo "<br>{$row['life']} - HP"; }?></div></TD>

<TD><div align="CENTER"><?php

$res2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attacks WHERE type = 'Fire'")or die("can't connect") ;    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res2 ) ){
echo "<br>{$row['name']}" ; }
?></div></TD>

<TD><div align="right"><?php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM enemy WHERE id = 1")or die("can't connect") ;    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ){
echo "<br>{$row['name']}" ;
echo " - {$row['level']} lvl";
echo "<br>{$row['img']}";
echo "<br>{$row['life']} - HP"; }?></div></TD>

</tr>
</table>
```

как теперь сделать чтоб атака сняла HP у Бота? А потом чтоб бот атаковал меня?

Comment: код для работы с БД в html'e - "здорово"...

Comment: Ну и что, если посмотреть то там можно увидеть как я открывал пхп

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$res = mysql_query("UPDATE `enemy` SET `life`='life-7' WHERE `id`='1'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
```

Если правильно понял. 7 хп снимаем при этом запросе

Comment: ага именно он =)

Comment: у него все столбики что и у покемона пользователя

Comment: а где узнать информацию о том сколько оружие занимает Hp? Как называется столик?

Comment: Значит у бота : life = 8 atk = 4

Comment: atk - это оружие или сколько снимает?

Comment: это сколько снимает, а оружие это атака EMBER